# SVG working in Chrome but not in FireFox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, svg

This is my first time working with SVGs. I have the following code which runs on Chrome but not on FF. Any clues?

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="18px" height="6px">
    <g>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FEDFBF" d="M0 0l8 6h1l8-6H0z" />
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FDFAD6" d="M1.562 0l6.555 5h0.765l6.534-5H1.562z" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Displays fine for me on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Example usage inline with HTML:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction

Example usage SVG as an Image:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_as_an_Image

Comment: Yes the first line is optional, thank you, I will edit.